# Apache Superset: stackable bar sort by value

Tags: apache-superset

Good afternoon!

I have a dataset that describes how many steps a person has taken at a time.

I build a stackable bar chart from this data so that I can see how many steps a certain person took in an hour.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gflx.png)

I'm having difficulty with a stackable column. I would like to sort inside a column of people not alphabetically, but by number of steps taken. For example, a person named "John" has walked the most and should be at the top of the column.

Is it possible to sort group by name within a stackable column?

To build a chart I use "Time-series Bar Chart v2"

I would be very grateful for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not currently possible under Superset 2.0.1.  See a related question, [How to customize the order of bars in a Superset Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73279908/how-to-customize-the-order-of-bars-in-a-superset-chart).